# Is it possible to transfer an apk from my mac to my android phone via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer

I only want to transfer from mac to android, not reverse and also achieve this via Bluetooth. Open to install any app on android

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can send files over Bluetooth. By default, android doesn't allow to receive every file type (many phones don't have this issue) so just rename the apk and add another acceptable extension like .jpg or .mp3 in the end. The Android phone should be able to receive the apk just fine. Now open the bluetooth folder and delete the added extension and you have your apk ready to install.